# My Mercury thermostat clicks on when I manipulate it but immediately shuts off

Tags: heating

My Mercury thermostat clicksks on/ off if I manipulate the dial by pushing in but then immediately shuts off. I checked housing it's ok but why would it not be turning my furnace on? It just immediately  shuts it off if I release any pressure

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you add some more info about the thermostat (e.g. make and model, and possibly a picture)? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: A mercury switch shouldn't 'click'.   And what do you mean, "release any pressure".  You set a thermostat and then that's it.

Answer (score 1):

From your description I believe it is a failure of the thermostat or a loose wire.

Is this a standard wet bulb with a bimetallic support?
(A glass globe with mercury and fine wires coming out of 1 end?) .

The most likely cause is the wires to the wet bulb are starting to fail, these thermostats normally last for decades but they do fail. Moving things may make the connection but when you let the pressure off it fails, if it continues to heat while you hold it that would be my first guess, second a loose wire.  I would remove the cover allowing access to the screws and snug them.

Depending on your location you may not be able to get a replacement because of the mercury but they make electronic ones that run on a 9v or a couple of AAA batteries and those are cheaper than the last Hg or mercury one I ordered.
(Some areas will not transport Hg or mercury containing products).

Comment: If the thermostat needs to be replaced, the old one shouldn't just be tossed in the trash. It should be taken to a recycling center that accepts mercury.